# codeblocks in ubuntu : code not running

Tags: ubuntu, code-blocks

I installed UBUNTU 15.04 onto my laptop in the same drive as Windows 8.1.
 When i try compiling and running a code on codeblocks in ubuntu, there is no output but this :
"sh: 1: /home/supreeth/Documents/Untitled1: Permission denied"

Comment: What's a code? Please explain more.

Comment: By code i just meant a simple c program.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark your file as executable:

```
 "chmod +x  /home/supreeth/Documents/Untitled1"
```

Comment: which file are you talking about?